# Como guardo variables de una petición a otra en servlets?

Tags: java, html, servlets

tengo un problemilla con un proyecto bastante simple de servlets en el que tengo que hacer una calculadora con codigo html y botones del tipo submit, pero tengo un problema que al darle al botón de suma o resta se me pone la pantalla a 0 en vez de a la suma. Un ejemplo de como debería funcionar:

Esta el 7 en pantalla, pulso 4, pulso el + y me debería aparecer 11 en pantalla.

Perdón por ponerlo en un principio en inglés, Muchas gracias!

```
        respuesta = request.getParameter("numero");
        String respuestaaux = request.getParameter("total");
        
        if(respuestaaux != null){
            total = Integer.parseInt(respuestaaux);
        }else{
            total = 0;            
            
        }
        
        if(respuesta == null){
            total = 0;
            
        }else if (respuesta.equals("-")){
            total = total - post;
            
        }else if (respuesta.equals("+")){            
            total = total + post;
        }else{
            ant = post;
            post = Integer.parseInt(respuesta);
            total = post;             
        }
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Calculadora online</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>" + total + "</h1>");
            request.setAttribute("total", total);
            out.println("<table>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='1'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='2'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
             ....
        
        }
        
        
    }
```

Al final he conseguido arreglarlo, lo dejo por aquí colgado por si a alguien le sirve, tal vez no es la mejor solución, acepto criticas ^^.

````
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        
        Object aux = new Object();  
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        
        
        String respuesta = "0";
        int ant;
        int post = 0;
        int total = 0;
        String raux = "0";
        respuesta = request.getParameter("numero");
        raux = request.getParameter("signo");
        aux = session.getAttribute("total");
        
        //control de ant
        if(aux != null){
            ant = Integer.parseInt(aux.toString());
        }else{
            ant = 0;            
            
        }        
        //control de post
        if(respuesta == null){
            total = 0;
               
        }else{
            
            post = Integer.parseInt(respuesta);
            total = post;             
        }
        
        //control de signo
        if (raux != null){
                aux = session.getAttribute("flotante");
                post = ant;
                if(aux != null){
                 ant = Integer.parseInt(aux.toString());
                }
            if(raux.equals("+")){
                total = ant + post;
                
            }
            if (raux.equals("-")){
                total = ant-post;
                
            }
            
        }
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Calculadora online</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>" + total + "</h1>");
            session.setAttribute("total", total);
            session.setAttribute("flotante",ant);
            out.println("<table>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='1'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='2'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
             out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='3'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("</tr>");
               out.println("<tr>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='4'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='5'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
             out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='6'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("</tr>");
            
               out.println("<tr>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='7'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='8'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
             out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='9'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("</tr>");
            
            out.println("<tr>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='numero' value='0'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='signo' value='+'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
             out.println("<td><form method = 'get'>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='signo' value='-'>");
            out.println("</form></td>");
            
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("</table>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        
        }
        ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hola para colaborar un poquito en tu pregunta solo podría hacer la crítica constructiva de que la primera vez que pusistes el código habia una variable llamada  String respuestaaux.

Como recomendación, para que mantengas buenas prácticas y legibilidad del código, se usa un concepto llamado camelCase y es  para denominar las variables de la siguiente manera String respuestaAux  en java las variables siempre comienzan en minúscula al igual que los métodos y las constantes en mayúscula, tal que así RESPUESTA_AUX. Espero que te haya servido esta información. Un saludo.